# RabbitMQ to simulate a topic exchange with a direct exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Is there a way I can have a direct exchange simulate a topic exchange (I know that the opposite can be obtained: [see here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/faq.html#fanout-direct-topic-specialisations)), but my use case here is that I already have deployed a direct exchange with lots of queues, each queue having the routing key `mykeyprefix.queue_name_here` and what I am trying to achieve is to have also a separate queue to which all of the messages from all the other queues end up for future analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, or at least not easily. Direct exchanges lack wildcard bindings, so the only option you'd have to do this with a direct exchange would be to add a duplicate queue for each of your possible routing keys and bind each of those new queues to the same exchange. Since you have lots of queues that's going to be quite messy.

Given that your requirement is met exactly by using a topic exchange, I'm curious as to why you can't just use that. Your producers won't care (since they just push messages to an Exchange) and your consumers won't need to change (since they just pull from a queue that could be bound to any type of Exchange). As for migration, you can bind the queues to both Exchanges and then unbind them from the old direct exchange. When you get every queue moved over you can then delete the direct exchange, leaving you with only that nice topic exchange that you really need.